# Convex Conjugate of sum-of-max terms

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, constraints

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a sum-of-max linear terms function:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^K \max_i\{a_{k,i}^\top x\}$$
where $a$ are the linear coefficients.

I am interested in the convex conjugate $f^*(w)$ of this function, then I will use a constraint $f^*(w) \leq 0$ in a convex optimization problem.

Recall the convex conjugate definition: $f^*(w) = \underset{x \in dom  f}{\sup} w^\top x - f(x)$

I try: 
$$\begin{align} 
& \underset{x \in dom  f}{\sup} w^\top x - f(x) \leq 0 \\
\iff & \sup \{ w^\top x -  \sum_{k=1}^K \max_i\{a_{k,i}^\top x\} \} \leq 0\\
\iff & \sup \{ w^\top x +  \sum_{k=1}^K \min_i\{-a_{k,i}^\top x\} \} \leq 0 \\
\iff & \sup \{ w^\top x + \sum_{k=1}^K y_k \  | \  y_k \leq \min_i \{ -a_{k,i}^\top x \},  \forall k\} \leq 0 \\
\iff & \begin{cases}
w^\top x + \sum_{k=1}^K y_k \leq 0 \\
y_k \leq -a_{k,i}^\top x \quad \forall i,k
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Obviously, the last steps are incorrect since $y_k \rightarrow - \infty$ will always hold the equation. This trick usually works for the $f(x) \leq 0$ kind of constraints, but I don't know how to linearize ths conjugate when we have $\sup$ of $-f(x)$.

Comment: okay, so $f(x)$ is not the correct way to formulate this. All the $a_{k,i}$ coefficients should be in the function input, and $f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^K \max_{i \subseteq {1,\ldots,n}} z_i$ is the better version. Then, we can say $f(Az + b)$, and so on..